# Sandbox Deployment Error - NotificationTypeConfig: record_collection_share is an invalid notification type

Tags: deployment, deployment-error, custom-notification, sharingrecordcollection

We are getting the following error when trying to deploy our project codebase into some sandbox provided by the client:

```
Error NotificationTypeConfig: record_collection_share is an invalid notification type
```

The thing here is that we've already successfully deployed our project into dozens of sandboxes and scratch orgs created by our own, but sandbox in question was created from another prod org and seems like it has a bit different configurations in terms of features enabled etc.

Does anyone have some clue re what feature/permission/setting is responsible for this **record_collection_share** notification type?

When we compare what is displayed in '*Setup -> Notification Builder -> Notification Delivery Settings*' of two sandboxes (client's and ours), we can see that '**Record Collection Sharing**' notification type is missing in client's org (screenshot provided from our sandbox, where it is available). But we have no clue how to make it appear in client's sandbox.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This should if EAC is available, Can you check if Einstein Activity Capture (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.einstein_sales_aac.htm&type=5) is active in missing org ?

Comment: @Vinay yes, it is missing in client's sandbox (no such item in setup at all), while it is available in our sandbox and prod org. Do you happen to know how we can make it available in client's sandbox or prod org. It's unlimited edition, so our guess is that it should have been available by default there. Any suggestion, please?

Comment: you should enable EAC, Setup-->Quick Find-->Einstein Activity Capture-->Settings-->Enable EAC.

Comment: @Vinay The problem is that it is not available in Setup at all in client's org.

Comment: Does user has (Customize Application OR Modify All Data, View Setup and Configurations) permissions? Also, try assigning [permission set](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.aac_setup_assign_standard.htm&type=5)

Comment: @Vinay We are using System Administrator user, i.e. all these permissions are in place. When we've tried to assign mentioned permission set, it has shown an error: "Failure: All Standard Einstein Activity Capture User permission set licenses are in use." Checking Setup -> Company tab, we see that 0 licenses are available for EAC and license is in disabled status.